# Converting Java objects to JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, json, object, jackson

I want my JSON to look like this:

```
{
    "information": [{
        "timestamp": "xxxx",
        "feature": "xxxx",
        "ean": 1234,
        "data": "xxxx"
    }, {
        "timestamp": "yyy",
        "feature": "yyy",
        "ean": 12345,
        "data": "yyy"
    }]
}
```

Code so far:

```
import java.util.List;

public class ValueData {

    private List<ValueItems> information;

    public ValueData(){

    }

    public List<ValueItems> getInformation() {
        return information;
    }

    public void setInformation(List<ValueItems> information) {
        this.information = information;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{information:%s}", information);
    }

}
```

and

```
public class ValueItems {

    private String timestamp;
    private String feature;
    private int ean;
    private String data;


    public ValueItems(){

    }

    public ValueItems(String timestamp, String feature, int ean, String data){
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.feature = feature;
        this.ean = ean;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getFeature() {
        return feature;
    }

    public void setFeature(String feature) {
        this.feature = feature;
    }

    public int getEan() {
        return ean;
    }

    public void setEan(int ean) {
        this.ean = ean;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{timestamp:%s,feature:%s,ean:%s,data:%s}", timestamp, feature, ean, data);
    }
}
```

I just missing the part how I can convert the Java object to JSON with Jackson:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // CONVERT THE JAVA OBJECT TO JSON HERE
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

My Question is: Are my classes correct? Which instance do I have to call and how that I can achieve this JSON output?

Comment: The following tutorial might help: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 670, accepted):

To convert your `object` in JSON with Jackson:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter; 

ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```

Comment: Only thing is the String comes out escaped from the ObjectWriter.

Use: 

new JSONObject(ow.writeValueAsString(msg)) 

if it's being sent out via Web Services like RESTful.

Comment: what is the fully qualifies package of `JSONObject `? I am not able to find it in jackson-databind libarary.

Comment: @MehrajMalik  ```import org.json.JSONObject``` Maven dependency: ```<dependency><groupId>org.json</groupId><artifactId>json</artifactId><version>20190722</version></dependency>```

Comment: How can I set the writer to ignore null fields or empty fields? I have set `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion = non_empty` in my Spring Boot application properties, however, that does not get applied here.

Answer (score 51):

I know this is old (and I am new to java), but I ran into the same problem. And the answers were not as clear to me as a newbie... so I thought I would add what I learned.

I used a third-party library to aid in the endeavor: `org.codehaus.jackson`
All of the downloads for this can be found [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson).

For base JSON functionality, you need to add the following jars to your project's libraries:
[jackson-mapper-asl](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl)
and
[jackson-core-asl](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl)

Choose the version your project needs. (Typically you can go with the latest stable build).

Once they are imported in to your project's libraries, add the following `import` lines to your code:

```
 import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
 import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

With the java object defined and assigned values that you wish to convert to JSON and return as part of a RESTful web service

```
User u = new User();
u.firstName = "Sample";
u.lastName = "User";
u.email = "sampleU@example.com";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
try {
    // convert user object to json string and return it 
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(u);
}
catch (JsonGenerationException | JsonMappingException  e) {
    // catch various errors
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The result should looks like this:
`{"firstName":"Sample","lastName":"User","email":"sampleU@example.com"}`

Comment: you made my day, thanks

Comment: just an update: catch JsonProcessingException instead of these two in version 2.12 or above.

Answer (score 46):

Just follow any of these:

- For **jackson** it should work:

  ```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        //will return json in string
  ```
- For **gson** it should work:

  ```
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      return Response.ok(gson.toJson(yourClass)).build();
  ```

Comment: What is Response.ok ?

Comment: I had a problem with JSON sizes inserted into mongoDB were above the allowed limit, when I turn on my Gson object has the larger size than with Jackson. Just a tip.

Comment: The question is about `jackson`, not `Gson`

Comment: @Codeversed Response is a class in the Jersey library. Response.ok will return JSON response with status code 200.

Answer (score 21):

You could do this:

```
String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(yourObjectHere);
```

Answer (score 17):

This might be useful:

```
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\employee.json"), employee);

// display to console
Object json = objectMapper.readValue(
     objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employee), Object.class);

System.out.println(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
     .writeValueAsString(json));
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use Google Gson like this

```
UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
user.setUserName("UserName");
user.setUserAge(18);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(user);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, even the accepted answer does not *exactly* output what op has asked for. It outputs the JSON string but with `"` characters escaped. So, although might be a little late, I am answering hopeing it will help people! Here is how I do it:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JsonGenerator jgen = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(writer);
jgen.setCodec(new ObjectMapper());
jgen.writeObject(object);
jgen.close();
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Note: To make the most voted solution work, attributes in the POJO have to be `public` or have a public `getter`/`setter`:

> By default, Jackson 2 will only work with fields that are either
>   public, or have a public getter method – serializing an entity that
>   has all fields private or package private will fail.

Not tested yet, but I believe that this rule also applies for other JSON libs like google Gson.

Answer (score 1):

with Spring

```
    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    ...
    json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(SomeObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JSONConvector {

    public static String toJSON(Object object) throws JSONException, IllegalAccessException {
        String str = "";
        Class c = object.getClass();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        for (Field field : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            String name = field.getName();
            String value = String.valueOf(field.get(object));
            jsonObject.put(name, value);
        }
        System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
        return jsonObject.toString();
    }


    public static String toJSON(List list ) throws JSONException, IllegalAccessException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for (Object i : list) {
            String jstr = toJSON(i);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jstr);
            jsonArray.put(jsonArray);
        }
        return jsonArray.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Too much work, too much reflection! Mappers are supposed to free you of doing these boilerplate stuff!

Comment: I love Convectors!

Comment: this is what your code look like when you get paid by lines

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can also use `cjson` library for converting java object to json string - [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.subhendushekhar.cjson/cjson)

```
CJson.toString()
```