# how to return data in json format to javascript ajax call

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json

I have the following method:

```
public String getUTResult() throws IOException {

     BuildResultParser bp = new BuildResultParser();
     BuildResultBean b = bp.getreadFile("C:\\bc.txt");

     String str = b.getuTresult();

     return str;
```

Now `str` variable contains the value as: `[0,5,5]`

Now I need to pass this value to ajax call in javascript in following format:

```
unittest
   {
     fail:0
     pass:5
     total:5
   }
```

Actually in javascript, I need this data in array format so that I can access each value and do some processing.

Comment: google servlet and ajax and you get a lot of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Read this : http://hmkcode.com/java-servlet-send-receive-json-using-jquery-ajax/ or any example of converting data to json format.

If your requirement is limited to the example, u can have another function which takes str and creates json data out of it, in the format required by you.

Comment: i am using jersy as of now and i dont want to use jquery

Comment: i dont know anyrhing about jquery , so is there any another way to generate such data

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson and http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/
Its not about jquery... Converting your object to a json object is a java code.. look at the java code in the examples..

Comment: u might want to read this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Always either accept an answer or post your own answer & mark it as the correct answer(if none of the answers provided is acceptable)..