# Converting two arrays into json string object using java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have two arrays,

```
id = [1,2,3]
pass = [a,b,c]
```

How do i convert it into below json structure, where it should start with '`[`' and end with '`]`',

```
  [
    { 
       "user": "1", 
       "password": "a"
    },
   { 
       "user": "1", 
       "password": "a"
    },
   { 
       "user": "1", 
       "password": "a"
    }
   ]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Java objects to JSON with Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson)

Comment: @baao I mapped the two tables and converted into json, but that i can get something like this, {"user":["1","2","3"],","password":["a","b","c"]}.

But i am not able to merge it like i wanted, also it is not covered with square brackets(array format)

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam i guess you want 1:a ,2:b and 3:c mapping but your example can also be achieved easily with little manipulation  with array indexes , let me know if you want the exact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
JSONObject obj;
for( int i = 0; i < yourUserArr.length; i++ ){
  obj = new JSONObject();
  obj.put("user", yourUserArr[i]);
  obj.put("password", yourPassArr[i]);
  arr.put( obj );
}
```

and guess you want this to send it to server in your required format then convert jsonarray into String

```
String data = arr.toString();
```