# Java JSON Creation

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON

```
{
        "display": {
            "icon": {
                "item": "minecraft:elytra"
            },
            "title": "Learn to Fly"
        },
        "parent": "minecraft:story/enter_end_gateway",
        "criteria": {
            "elytra": {
                "trigger": "minecraft:inventory_changed",
                "conditions": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "item": "minecraft:elytra",
                            "data": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How would I be able to create this within Java?

Along with being able to get each element, eg the title.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to parse this JSON?

Comment: No, I want to create this myself with different values of course (for Minecraft .JSON Achievements). I would like to know how I could go and create each element (even if you used your own example)

Comment: Use this if you want to create a Java POJO http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ this can help yo to create classes representing the JSON

Comment: Try this http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/ paste your json and generate pojo

Comment: Wow! Thank you all of you :)

Comment: May I ask, what is pogo? I've wanted to create something as a single OOP class.

Comment: POJO for Plain Old Java Object. we can say a simple class with getters and setters for its members.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Java objects to JSON with Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson)

Comment: You were not able to google "java convert object to json" but you were able to create a question on stackoverflow? Very suspicious.

Comment: @displayname I had already looked and could not find exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to build your json with org.json library in java:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONBuilderMinecraft {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject();



        //inner most json array
        JSONArray itemarray=new JSONArray();

        //inner most json
        JSONObject itemsJson= new JSONObject();
        itemsJson.put("item", "minecraft:elytra");
        itemsJson.put("data", 1);
        itemarray.put(itemsJson);

        JSONObject conditions = new JSONObject();
        conditions.put("items", itemarray);


        JSONObject elytra = new JSONObject();
        elytra.put("trigger", "minecraft:inventory_changed");
        elytra.put("conditions", conditions);


        mainJson.put("criteria", elytra);
        mainJson.put("parent", "minecraft:story/enter_end_gateway");

        JSONObject icon = new JSONObject();
        icon.put("item", "minecraft:elytra");

        JSONObject display = new JSONObject();
        display.put("title", "Learn to Fly");
        display.put("icon", icon);

        mainJson.put("display", display);

        System.out.println(mainJson.toString());

    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Accepted this answer!

Comment: that is a hard-coded solution which is difficult to maintain and read, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, its just a point to start with. Of course you will be sending dynamic values to replace hard coded values. I would recommend gson library as well.

Comment: I've got it all sorted with dynamic values and such, what would I do to have like "criteria": {
            "elytra": { (and having items inside this

Answer (score 2):

check this library [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)  from google its easy to use and have a lot of APIs to work with JSON

Comment: Thank you! As said above

Comment: @Chazmondo, checkout the documentation on github: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Primitives-Examples

Answer (score 2):

The process you are asking about is called unmarshalling (parsing a serialised object in JSON/XML/other formats into an object to work with within the object-oriented context).

I would recommend having a look at [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). It's a popular library which is used in such the well-known frameworks like Spring (the MVC module). 
Having created a domain object, you could transform a `jsonData` into an `instance` of the `DomainClass` class like

```
DomainClass instance = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonData, DomainClass.class);
```

The `jsonData` source can be `File`s, `InputStream`s, `byte` arrays, `String`s and [so on](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.io.File,%20java.lang.Class)). It's up to you to pick up the most convenient way to obtain that data.

> Along with being able to get each element, eg the title.

When the instance is ready, you are free to get *elements* (now *fields*) through the accessors (the `get` methods).

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating your code like this stupid idea

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonObject2=new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonObject3=new JSONObject();

jsonObject.put("display",jsonObject3);
```

you can use [Gson](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/), so simple it creates json object without wasting your time on code make a class for each new Json object and make a relations between them.

Comment: Thank you! GSON is within the Spigot jar (by minecraft).

Comment: Could you give me a couple examples with gson?

Answer (score -1):

Try this,it works fine:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String jsonString = "{\n"
                + "        \"display\": {\n"
                + "            \"icon\": {\n"
                + "                \"item\": \"minecraft:elytra\"\n"
                + "            },\n"
                + "            \"title\": \"Learn to Fly\"\n"
                + "        },\n"
                + "        \"parent\": \"minecraft:story/enter_end_gateway\",\n"
                + "        \"criteria\": {\n"
                + "            \"elytra\": {\n"
                + "                \"trigger\": \"minecraft:inventory_changed\",\n"
                + "                \"conditions\": {\n"
                + "                    \"items\": [\n"
                + "                        {\n"
                + "                            \"item\": \"minecraft:elytra\",\n"
                + "                            \"data\": 1\n"
                + "                        }\n"
                + "                    ]\n"
                + "                }\n"
                + "            }\n"
                + "        }\n"
                + "    }";

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject disp = object.getJSONObject("display");
        String title = disp.getString("title");

        System.out.println("title is " + title);
    }
```

Comment: The question was to create the json, not retrieve data after building it like your above code.

Comment: yeah exactly, I think he can use json in string format like in my code