# How to store the state of Java bean in a non web application?

Tags: java, rft

As part of my RFT QA Automation, I have to store the state(Object) of Java bean  and should access the object across the whole application, Singleton may not work here as it is not a web application, would you please suggest any other approach to store the state of java beans.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: singleton doesn't have anything to do with web application

Comment: you can use singleton

Comment: But by the time I try to access the object it may be claimed by GC and it will create a new instance and I will loose the state.I would like to hold the same state through out the application until my test scripts completed.

Comment: GC won't touch your singleton because it references to itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your problem but why not:

- serialize the objects to disk/database/...
- use a static store (static singleton)

Comment: I can create a class with static Map which has all the values, but I need a class with setters and getters like a java bean..

Comment: You can also create:a class containing static objects or a static map containing objects then you can use getter and setter:

-MyClass.myStaticObject.getX()/MyClass.MyStaticObject.setX("val")
-MyClass.myStaticMap.get("objId").getX()/MyClass.myStaticMap.get("objId").setX("val")

Comment: Your object will never be GC collected while a reference to the object exists.  The only exception to this rule is when you're using Weak reference (WeakHashMap,...)

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is a typical Serialization/Deserialization issue. In general you need an ability to write the state of the class on to persistant layer and then to be able to restore the "same" instance from persistant layer. There is a built-in Java mechanizm that works through `Serializable` interface. However it is rarely used due to its inconvinience. One of te most popular ways to do this is to Serialize your class instances into JSON or XML format and then read it back and instanciate it from that format. If you need the Text to be human readable XML is preferred, otherwise JSON is the usual choice. The best tool to use for JSON serialization is JSON Jackson (FasterXML/jackson) Here are the relevant links: [Json Jackson home](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs). The main class that you will need to use is [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html). It is easy to use. Here is an article with [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson). Once you get a Json String of your instance write it into a file or DB and then read it and use `ObjectMapper` to -recreate your instance. It is simple and works very well