# Map multiiple Java pojo fields to one json field with Jackson annotations

Tags: java, json, mapping, jsonresponse

I'm trying to map two fields from Java POJO to one json field;

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;

    //this two fields should be in separate json property (object)
    private String street;
    private String streetNo;
...
    //getters and setters
}
```

And I want to get response something like this:

```
{
    firstName: "Peter",
    address: {
        street: "Square nine",
        streetNumber: "12"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Micko. Welcome to SO community. In order to keep our community clean and avoid duplication of questions I can point you to the duplicated question that you have asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Java objects to JSON with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement then another POJO Address and add `address` field to your Person POJO

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;

    private Address address = new Address();

...
    //getters and setters
}

// another POJO
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String streetNo;

    //getters and setters
}
```