# JSON object to BODY publisher

Tags: java, http, httprequest

I am working on a project where i request an api to post an item details. The following is my code where i tried to insert a body itemstr using HttpRequest

```
 public void test(){
        newItem item = new newItem(12,12,12,21,"waiwai");
        JSONObject itemobj = new JSONObject(item);
        String itemStr = itemobj.toString();
        System.out.println(itemStr);
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("http://localhost:3001/postMongo")).POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(itemStr)).build();

    }
```

this is my newItem class

```
public class newItem {
    int id,wholesaleRate,SellingPrice,stock;
    String name;

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getWholesaleRate() {
        return wholesaleRate;
    }

    public void setWholesaleRate(int wholesaleRate) {
        this.wholesaleRate = wholesaleRate;
    }

    public int getSellingPrice() {
        return SellingPrice;
    }

    public void setSellingPrice(int sellingPrice) {
        SellingPrice = sellingPrice;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public newItem(int id, int wholesaleRate, int sellingPrice, int stock, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.wholesaleRate = wholesaleRate;
        this.SellingPrice = sellingPrice;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I am trying to post the itemStr as a body to a restful API that i run locally. I could retrieve using the GET request but could not post.

Comment: You have to explain more. I honestly don't understand what you want to do. Give us more information about "newItem" and the final object format you want to have.

Comment: I have edited my post. Id be very happy if you could help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OpenJDK has posted a recipe for bridging the new Java 11 HTTP client and Jackson:
http://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/recipes.html#jsonPost

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String requestBody = objectMapper
      .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
      .writeValueAsString(map);

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri)
      .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(requestBody))
      .build();

return HttpClient.newHttpClient()
      .sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString())
      .thenApply(HttpResponse::statusCode)
      .thenAccept(System.out::println);
```

Hopefully Jackson will soon implement `BodyPublisher` itself instead of having to serialize to a string first...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `GSON`

```
UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
user.setUserName("UserName");
user.setUserAge(18);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(user);
```

Please refer to this post to convert your object to JSON:
[Converting Java objects to JSON with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson)

Comment: The itemStr printed above is {"sellingPrice":12,"wholesaleRate":12,"name":"waiwai","id":12,"stock":21} . I think the BODY have to be string if im using .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(itemStr))

Comment: isn't that what you want?

Comment: its not sending anything to the api. But when im sending the output above in postman it is correct