# Add Duplicate Keys in JSON - Java

Tags: java, json

```json
{
    "student": [
        {
            "name": "TEST",
            "id": "1234",
            "@class" : "10"
        }
    ],
    "student": [
        {
            "name": "TEST12",
            "id": "1235",
            "@class" : "12"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to generate the JSON like this from classObj or any other way?

Comment: Instead of one array per "student" make it one array for all student records, `"student": [{"name":...}, {"name":...}]`

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson.  I need structure like this instead of one array. Is it possible?

Comment: No, you don't need that. I of course have no idea what you are trying to do here but you need to re-think your solution or you have misunderstood some requirement because you can't have duplicate keys and there is really no point in having them either.

Comment: If you must have a structure that looks like this then can you replace "student" at the outer level with something that is actually a map key such as the "id" element from the student details map?

Answer (score 1):

The format you describe, with duplicated keys, is not a good one. As [RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-4) says:

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

As such, you're unlikely to find a library that makes it easy to generate this format, and you can't predict which `student` consumers would use.

It's reasonable to compose JSON as strings, if you're careful. The outer structure is simple. Generate it by concatenating hardcoded strings of JSON, then concatenate a [generated `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson) for each individual `student` object.

Answer (score 0):

This is considered an invalid JSON as per [RFC-8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-4).

Instead you can group your students in an array

```json
{
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "TEST",
            "id": "1234",
            "@class" : "10"
        },
        {
            "name": "TEST12",
            "id": "1235",
            "@class" : "12"
        }
    ]
}
```