# How to retrieve AWS Textract response JSON using the Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ocr

I am using AWS Textract to OCR images and create a searchable PDF as outlined in this AWS [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/generating-searchable-pdfs-from-scanned-documents-automatically-with-amazon-textract/).
The basic request code looks like this:

```
AmazonTextractClientBuilder builder = AmazonTextractClientBuilder.standard();
DetectDocumentTextRequest request = new DetectDocumentTextRequest()
                .withDocument(new Document()
                        .withBytes(imageBytes));
DetectDocumentTextResult result = client.detectDocumentText(request);
List<Block> blocks = result.getBlocks()
```

This works out great however I would also like to write out and keep the original response JSON that contains all the information on what was detected where etc.

Is there a way to get to the response JSON using the JAVA SDK?

Answer (score 0):

AWS doesn't return the response JSON to you in raw form. The assumption may have been that it wouldn't be required once it has been converted to a `DetectDocumentTextResult` object.

You are able to convert the `DetectDocumentTextResult` object to JSON ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15786175/3474282)) which should provide identical values. Note that the variable names will not be identical (e.g.: `DocumentMetadata` vs `documentMetadata`) but the values of those variables will be the same.