# Java to JSON: Specify which fields get excluded for each conversion

Tags: java, json, jackson

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson), I know that I can convert Java objects to JSON (with Jackson)

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(objectToBeConverted);
```

I know that I can exclude fields from being included in the JSON string using the `@JsonIgnore` annotation, but what if I want to convert the same class to JSON multiple times, but each time choosing different fields to ignore?

For example, if I have a class

```
class Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    ...
}
```

can I do something like

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
String json1 = ow.writeValueAsString(foo).excludeField('b');
String json2 = ow.writeValueAsString(foo).excludeField('a');
```

so that the resulting strings look like

```
// json1
{
    a: 1234
}
```

```
// json2
{
    b: 5678
}
```

If Jackson can't do it, maybe Gson can? Or another library?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using different mix-in interfaces. I found two ways to do this.

1. Use methods for reading properties. You can then create a mix-in class that only defines the properties to exclude:

   ```
   public interface ExludeA {
       @JsonIgnore
       int getA();
   }
   ```
2. Use `@JsonIncludeProperties` to not tell which properties to *exclude*, but which properties to *include*:

   ```
   @JsonIncludeProperties({ "b", "c" })
   public interface ExludeA {
   }
   ```

In both cases, add that mix-in to the object mapper:

```
objectMapper.addMixIn(Foo.class, ExcludeA.class);
```

There is one very, very important thing though - you must use a new `ObjectMapper` for each mix-in. If you use an `ObjectMapper` instance to serialize a `Foo` instance without mix-ins, then adding the mix-in won't help. That's probably because `ObjectMapper` instances cache some stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach if you could box up all primitive type in `Foo`.

For example: `int -> Integer`, `boolean -> Boolean`

```java
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class Foo {
    Integer a;
    Integer b;
    ...
}
```

Then, just make a copy of `Foo` and set the property which you want to ignore to `null`.

```java
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setA(1234);
foo.setB(5678);

Foo foo1 = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(foo), Foo.class);  // make a copy of Foo
foo1.setB(null);  // force to ignore B
String json1 = ow.writeValueAsString(foo1); // it will be {a:1234}
```

Comment: Its helpful for my case, but I guess it doesn't cover the case where you want to include null values. Thanks though!

Comment: yeah, not a perfect solution but good enough.  =)

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple solution based on your need:

***First:*** 
You can just define two different *DTO* for your purpose and every time you need to each one just use it.

---

***Second:*** 
You can use `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotation for the properties:

```
class Foo {

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    int a;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    int b;
}
```

P.S: You can use this annotation on class level as:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) 
class Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

---

***Third:*** 
Use can define a filter to ignore properties based on different conditions.

Define a simple class for your filter:

```
public class YourConditionalFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(int a) {
        return a == 1234;
    }
}
```

And then add this filter as annotation on top of the property:

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = YourConditionalFilter.class)
int a;
```

Comment: What does the `return a == 1;` accomplish?

Comment: It's based on your condition, return true if you want to ignore or vice versa @DaMike

Comment: But I won't know `a`'s value before hand. I don't care what its value is actually. I just want to ignore it from json whatever its value.

Comment: You can use Two different DTO's for your need or define a filter like this in confitional situation. I think there is no other choice and you can't ignore properties as you said with an *excludeField* method @DaMike

Comment: Do you have tries `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotation on top of your properties `a` and `b`?This annotation just ignore null values and result will look like what you want. @Da Mike