# How to convert a list of java objects into a list of maps

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I have the following domain object

```
Class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

and I have a `List<Student>`

How do I convert that into a list of map as follows

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "age": 2
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "pqr",
    "age": 3
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to create a method `toHashMap()` in your `Student` class:

```
public LinkedHashMap<String,Object> toHashMap(){
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> h = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    h.put("Id",id);
    h.put("Name", name);
    h.put("Age",age);
    return h;
}
```

I use a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the insertion order. Once that is done, try this:

```
List<Student> ls = new ArrayList<>();
ls.add(new Student(12123,"Tom",12));
ls.add(new Student(12354,"George",21));
ls.add(new Student(12245,"Sara",16));
ls.add(new Student(17642,"Caitlyn",11));


List<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>> names = ls.stream().map(Student::toHashMap).collect( Collectors.toList() );

System.out.println(names);
```

Output: `[{Id=12123, Name=Tom, Age=12}, {Id=12354, Name=George, Age=21}, {Id=12245, Name=Sara, Age=16}, {Id=17642, Name=Caitlyn, Age=11}]`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say getting the object and iterating on the declared fields is good enough for what you're trying to do. Something like this:

```java
private static List<Map<String,Object>> objectsToMap(List<Object> objects) throws IllegalAccessException {
  List<Map<String,Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Object object : objects) {
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
      var oldAccessibility = field.canAccess(object);
      field.setAccessible(true);
      var value = field.get(object);
      map.put(field.getName(), value);
      field.setAccessible(oldAccessibility);
    }
    result.add(map);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Nevertheless, it seems like you're trying to convert an ordinary object to JSON strings and there are libraries that to that super well. Check out this [stackoverflow thread about conversion of objects to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson) if this is really what you're trying to achieve.